# Glossy BSDF on Image Texture with transparency

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I am new to blender and I am trying to add gloss to my image and it works, except the transparency on the image is black instead of transparent and I have no idea how to solve it with nodes. What do I have to do to make the black parts of the Image Texture transparent?

This is what I came up with:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way for you to connect your nodes would be like this. The mix shader gives you better control over the "glossiness" of the image:

[image: Gloss]

Don't forget to make sure the *Blend Mode* is set to something other than *opaque* (pictured as *Alpha Blend* on right hand side).

Or (even easier in my opinion) - use a Principled BSDF shader and turn up the Metallic and/or turn down the Roughness:

[image: Gloss2]

Answer (score 2):

You’ve got color going directly into one of the shader sockets. It will be interpreted basically like an emission shader (always showing the same color no matter what the illumination conditions and this like a light bulb), but since the alpha is switching to it when the image is supposed to be blank, it ends up “emitting” black. What you want is the image color going into the Glossy node color input, the Glossy node output going into the second Shader socket of the mix shader node, alpha from the image going into the Factor input (like it is), and a transparent shader going into the first Shader socket. Also, the alpha mode needs to be set to clip or hash in material settings.